# Discord.js Database

Tags: sql, discord.js

I have made a bot called ["Hello Bot"](https://discordbots.org/bot/498514150306086922) but I want to have a database connection so I can do more things but I can not find a way to do it on will you help me?

Comment: I personally use [mLab](https://mlab.com/) to host my database. It's free and pretty easy to learn to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [SQLite](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system) or [Enmap](https://enmap.evie.codes/) depending on what you're trying to do. You could also link into MySQL by running `npm install mysql` in your bot's directory and adding the following code at the top of your bot's js file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'hostname',
  port     : 'portnum',
  user     : 'db_user',
  password : 'db_user_password',
  database : 'db_name',
  charset : 'utf8mb4'
});
```

Note that you will have to install and setup MySQL on your server and create your database.

Here are a couple more links regarding setting my Node.js with Database access:
https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-node-js-with-a-database-part-1-3f2461bdd77f
https://tr-center.com/line/discord-js-bot-tutorial-part-6-xp-system-with-mysql-E5TVwyiCuYA.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the game on this one. But what I did with mine is used a atlas mongodb. I have my bot hosted on Amazon's AWS so connecting to a cloud DB was pretty easy from a nodejs project.